# Producing the same output as Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]?

Tags: expression-construction

How can I use the functions `decimalToBinary` and `padWithZeros` to produce the same output as `Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: What are "decimalToBinary" and "padWithZeros"? Is this a homework assignment and are those functions introduced in your course?

Answer (score 4):

It all can be done in one command:

```
a = Table[IntegerDigits[k, 2, 4], {k, 0, 15}]
```

Or:

```
a = IntegerDigits[Range[0, 15], 2, 4]
```

The 2nd argument = 2 is the base we want and the 4 pads the answer on the left for both commands.

```
 (*{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 
      0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 
      0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 
      1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}*)

a - Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]

(*{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}*)
```

Showing that we have the same output.